# Summation Expression with Range and Sequence expression

Tags: summation, spline

I've been trying to search for the meaning for this summation for a couple of days now. I've used https://approach0.xyz/ to search on the stack, but I cannot seem to find an explanation that helps me.

All I know that it is supposed to be a spline equation, but I don't understand, with my limited math knowledge, the range and sequence sign in this summation.

$g(u)=\sum_{i=0}^{\ n\ }\ 1\left\{\left[u_i,u_{i+1}\right)\right\}s_i\left(u\right)$

$s_i(u)= d_i(u - u_i)^3 + c_i(u-u_i)^2 + b_i(u-u_i)+a_i$

[Full Equation Here from paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awmgo.png)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $X$, the *[indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)* or *characteristic function* of a set $A\subseteq X$ is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{1}_{A}=
\begin{cases}
1&\qquad x\in A\\
0&\qquad x\not \in A
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Here we consider the set $X=\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers and for each interval $\left[u_i,u_{i+1}\right)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $0\leq i\leq n$ we consequently have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{1}_{\left[u_i,u_{i+1}\right)}=
\begin{cases}
1&\qquad x\in \left[u_i,u_{i+1}\right)\\
0&\qquad x\not \in \left[u_i,u_{i+1}\right)
\end{cases}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> The function $g$ is given in terms of (1). It can be written as
> \begin{align*}
> g(u)&=\sum_{i=0}^n\mathbb{1}_{\left[u_i,u_{i+1}\right)}s_i(u)\\
> &=\mathbb{1}_{\left[u_0,u_{1}\right)}s_0(u)+\mathbb{1}_{\left[u_1,u_{2}\right)}s_1(u)
> +\cdots+\mathbb{1}_{\left[u_n,u_{n+1}\right)}s_n(u)\\
> &=\begin{cases}
> s_0(u)&\qquad x\in\left[u_0,u_{1}\right)\\
> s_1(u)&\qquad x\in\left[u_1,u_{2}\right)\\
> \quad\vdots&\\
> s_n(u)&\qquad x\in\left[u_n,u_{n+1}\right)\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

Note, the usage of braces $1_{\{[u_i,u_{i+1}\}}$ surrounding the interval is not correct, since each of the intervals $[u_i,u_{i+1})$ is already the set we want to use.